# What is the easiest, quick and foolproof way to undo a git rebase?

Tags: git, git-rebase

I am new to Git rebasing and want to be able to revert a rebase completely and easily. I found solutions that involve several steps and use advanced commands like `git reflog`. I am afraid I won't be able to apply those correctly and/or will need a lot of time to figure out what exactly to do.

**Is there an easy, quick and foolproof solution, even if it's "dumb"?**

My own "dumb" solution: Duplicate the project folder on a file system level and then after a "failed" rebase just delete the original folder and rename the backup to the originals name.

Comment: Did you push the rebase?

Comment: @AkramFares: No

Comment: You can try checkout commit id before rebase

Comment: Did you try "git reset --hard origin/master"? "master" is your current branch.

Answer (score 1):

The reference, "[ORIG_HEAD](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions)" stores the previous HEAD commit and will undo a rebase or a merge.

`git reset --hard ORIG_HEAD`

From the documentation:

> ORIG_HEAD is created by commands that move your HEAD in a drastic way, to record the position of the HEAD before their operation, so that you can easily change the tip of the branch back to the state before you ran them

The documentation suggests it's designed for this specific purpose.

Comment: _most cases_ I would be afraid it would not work for me and would need to invest time to find out what the exceptions are. :)

Comment: I just said that to cover my arse. The documentation does state it's designed for that purpose! Problems only really arise when people have got themselves into a mess and aren't sure what commands they've run, whether the rebase was the last command they ran, that kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

before doing a rebase push your current work to your git server (github etc).

then you can safely rebase and if you want to revert you can just delete the folder and clone it from the server. or reset to the upstream head.

Comment: If I want to use rebase to clean up the local commit history of my feature branch before pushing it to the public repository. So this not a viable option unfortunately. Still a good solution for other use cases.

Answer (score 0):

As long as this is purely local, that is, you're not pushing your branch between rebasing and potentially reverting, just start out by creating an additional backup branch, at the same commit as you are rebasing from. That branch will then stay the same, and you can just reset to that, should something go wrong. And the backup branch will stay around until you specifically delete it.

Create the backup branch with:

```
git branch backup
```

Then do the rebase:

```
git rebase <branch-to-rebase-on>
```

If you want to revert after the rebase is completed, just do:

```
git reset --hard backup
```

This will reset your current branch to the same commit as backup, which is where you started out before the rebase. Note that any changes or new commits made will be discarded though!

If you find out during the rebase (while fixing conflicts for instance), that you want to cancel the rebase, you can always do:

```
git rebase --abort
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do use `ORIG_HEAD` to reset and cancel a rebase, make sure to use a Git 2.22 (Q2 2019)

> "`git rebase`" that was reimplemented in C did not set `ORIG_HEAD` correctly, which has been corrected.

See [commit cbd29ea](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cbd29ead92d8555f2b918c7f9d53913f26f7a872), [commit c2d9629](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c2d96293602bf6e8ffa1002cff8cb6faa3854815), [commit eaf8160](https://github.com/git/git/commit/eaf81605b8d17cc15a4a72ffd99d71111b70815b), [commit e6aac81](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e6aac8177d02691bebedec56376ed17239793f9f) (03 Mar 2019) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 9fbcc3d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9fbcc3d2036569d501bf222e700a4c017547a267), 20 Mar 2019)</sup>

> ### built-in `rebase`: set `ORIG_HEAD` just once, before the rebase
>
> Technically, the scripted version set `ORIG_HEAD` only in two spots (which
>   really could have been one, because it called `git checkout $onto^0` to
>   start the rebase and also if it could take a shortcut, and in both cases
>   it called `git update-ref $orig_head`).
>
> Practically, it *implicitly* reset `ORIG_HEAD` whenever `git reset --hard`
>   was called.
>
> However, what we really want is that it is set exactly once, at the
>   beginning of the rebase.
>
> So let's do that.
>
> ### built-in rebase: no need to check out `onto` twice
>
> In the case that the rebase boils down to a fast-forward, the built-in
>   rebase reset the working tree twice:
>
> - once to start the rebase at `onto`,
> - then realizing that the original (pre-rebase) HEAD was an ancestor and
>     we basically already fast-forwarded to the post-rebase HEAD,
>     `reset_head()` was called to update the original ref and to point HEAD
>     back to it.
>
> That second `reset_head()` call does not need to touch the working tree,
>   though, as it does not change the actual tip commit (and therefore the
>   working tree should stay unchanged anyway): only the ref needs to be
>   updated (because the rebase detached the HEAD, and we want to go back to
>   the branch on which the rebase was started).